# Why does my 'secret message/code-breaking' code not work?

Tags: python-3.x

I have created a code that (should) be able to convert a string into an ascii 'code'. However, it doesn't output what i want it to. Here is the code concerned:

```
if Code_Decode=='C':
    print("What is your 'Shift number'?")
    SNum=int(input("> "))
    print("What is your message?")
    msg=input("> ")
    code=[ord(c) for c in msg]
    new_code=[x+(SNum) for x in code]
    print(','.join(str(x) for x in code))
else:
    print("What is your 'Shift number'?")
    SNum=int(input("> "))
    print("Type in your ASCII values, separated by a comma")
    a = [int(x) for x in input().split(",")]
    ans=[x-(SNum) for x in a]
    ans2=[chr(i) for i in ans]
    print(' '.join(str(x) for x in ans2))
```

The user should input a 'Shift Number', then a string, And it should be converted into ascii, with the Shift Number added to each individual value.
However, when I run the code, the shift number is not added. Ignore the if and else lines.
**Example:** (This is what happens when I run the code)

```
Do you want to Create(C) a message, or Decode(D) a message? (C/D)> C
What is your 'Shift number'?
> 2
What is your message?
> Hello World
72,101,108,108,111,32,87,111,114,108,100
Again? Y/N > Y
Do you want to Create(C) a message, or Decode(D) a message? (C/D)> D
What is your 'Shift number'?
> 2
Type in your ASCII values, separated by a comma
72,101,108,108,111,32,87,111,114,108,100
F c j j m  U m p j b
```

As you can see, the program outputs with some jumbled-up letters. How do I fix it?

Comment: Sorry about the poor formatting, I am new to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Wrong: print(','.join(str(x) for x in code))
Right: print(','.join(str(x) for x in new_code))
```